# Is there a way to select an array without specifying it

Tags: java, android

I want to get a number from an array, without having to do a lot of if statements.

```
double[] PVC_A1_Cu = new double[]{14.5d, 19.5d, 26.0d, 34.0d, 46.0d, 61.0d, 80.0d, 99.0d, 119.0d, 151.0d, 182.0d, 210.0d, 240.0d, 273.0d, 321.0d, 367.0d};
double[] PVC_A2_Cu = new double[]{14.0d, 18.5d, 25.0d, 32.0d, 43.0d, 57.0d, 75.0d, 92.0d, 110.0d, 139.0d, 167.0d, 192.0d, 219.0d, 148.0d, 291.0d, 334.0d};
double[] PVC_B1_Cu = new double[]{17.5d, 24.0d, 32.0d, 41.0d, 57.0d, 76.0d, 101.0d, 125.0d, 151.0d, 192.0d, 232.0d, 269.0d, 300.0d, 341.0d, 400.0d, 458.0d};
double[] PVC_B2_Cu = new double[]{16.5d, 23.0d, 30.0d, 38.0d, 52.0d, 69.0d, 90.0d, 111.0d, 133.0d, 168.0d, 201.0d, 232.0d, 258.0d, 294.0d, 344.0d, 394.0d};

String Kappe = SpinLederKapp.getSelectedItem().toString();   // This would return "PVC"
String LederMat = SpinLederMat.getSelectedItem().toString(); // This would return "A1"
String InsMet = SpinInsMet.getSelectedItem().toString();     //This would return  "Cu"

Integer Tverrsnitt = SpinTverrsnitt.getSelectedItemPosition();  //This would return in this case   "2"

String Codetest = Kappe + "_" + InsMet + "_"+LederMat;  //this would put it together like "PVC_A1_Cu"

Double Test3 = Codetest[Tverrsnitt];  //And here is were my knowledge ends...
//This does not work ^

//What i want it to do:
Double Test1 = PVC_A1_Cu[2];
```

Comment: When asking for help, it's best to stick to the standard naming conventions, as it makes it much easier for people to read your code and help you. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.) Variable names start with lower case, so for instance, `kappe` instead of `Kappe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the arrays in a `Map` (probably once and then keep it at the class level):

```
Map<String, double[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("PVC_A1_Cu", new double[]{14.5d, 19.5d, 26.0d, 34.0d, 46.0d, 61.0d, 80.0d, 99.0d, 119.0d, 151.0d, 182.0d, 210.0d, 240.0d, 273.0d, 321.0d, 367.0d});
map.put("PVC_A2_Cu", new double[]{14.0d, 18.5d, 25.0d, 32.0d, 43.0d, 57.0d, 75.0d, 92.0d, 110.0d, 139.0d, 167.0d, 192.0d, 219.0d, 148.0d, 291.0d, 334.0d});
map.put("PVC_B1_Cu", new double[]{17.5d, 24.0d, 32.0d, 41.0d, 57.0d, 76.0d, 101.0d, 125.0d, 151.0d, 192.0d, 232.0d, 269.0d, 300.0d, 341.0d, 400.0d, 458.0d});
map.put("PVC_B2_Cu", new double[]{16.5d, 23.0d, 30.0d, 38.0d, 52.0d, 69.0d, 90.0d, 111.0d, 133.0d, 168.0d, 201.0d, 232.0d, 258.0d, 294.0d, 344.0d, 394.0d});
```

and then use it with your `Codetest` string:

```
double Test3 = map.get(Codetest)[Tverrsnitt];
```

Note that I ued `double`, not `Double`, since the arrays are of primitive doubles, not `Double` instances.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you understand what's going wrong here.

First you are creating a double array,

```
double[] PVC_A1_Cu = ..... //This means create a variable of type double array whose name is PVC_A1_Cu.
```

Later you are creating a string variable,

```
String Codetest = ... //This means create a variable of type String whose name is codetest
```

At last you are assigning a value "PVC_A1_Cu" (which happens to be your double array variable name) to your string variable Codetest. This is no way means that you are referring to the content of the double array, it just means that your string variable has a content "PVC_A1_Cu" and cannot be referred like an array. So the compiler will complain when your code does this,

```
Codetest[Tverrsnitt]; //codeTest is not an array
```

The simplest way you could handle this is,

```
if("PVC_A1_Cu".equals(Codetest)) {
    test3 = PVC_A1_Cu[Tverrsnitt];
} else ("PVC_A2_Cu".equals(Codetest)) {
    test3 = PVC_A2_Cu[Tverrsnitt];
} else ("PVC_B1_Cu".equals(Codetest)) {
    test3 = PVC_B1_Cu[Tverrsnitt];
} else {
    test3 = PVC_B2_Cu[Tverrsnitt];
}
```